# What elements will a div auto height by?

Tags: css, html, height

I have a div with `height:auto;`

I do see that it will resize based on some elements. It does resize with just plain text for instance.
However, if i set a child div with specified size, the parent `height:auto;` div will not resize to fit around that child div.

So i was wandering if maybe changing the Display type would help? (no luck so far though).

Thanks

EDIT:
There are no floats inside the parent div, if not absolute elements are considered float?
The parent div is position:relative;
and the child div is absolute.
When i tried to use overflow:auto; on the parent div, scroll bars appeared on the parent div instead if making it bigger when needed.

Thanks for the replies!

```
<div style="height: auto; position:relative">
<div style="height: 50px; position:absolute;">ALOHA</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do inner elements have specific position? or float?

Comment: Where is the code? That's the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your child DIV or content is floated.  On its own, `height: auto;` will not scale around this as it doesn't recognise floats as a part of the regular document order.

Your best solution is probably to use `overflow: auto;` on your parent DIV.

Alternatively, if floats *are* responsible, your parent DIV will also wrap around floated content if you apply a float to the parent itself.  This may not be ideal, though, because this will affect its placement - so `overflow: auto;` is most likely better.

If you can provide any examples of your code, I'm sure someone can give you a more specific example.

Answer (score 0):

Div doesn't fill parent div, but if you'll change your structure like thi:

```
<div style="height: auto">
 foo bar foo bar<div style="height: 200px">heya</div>
<div class="clear" style="clear: both"></div>
</DIV>
```

`height:auto` will works.

edited ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean something like

```
<div style="height: auto">
<div style="height: 50px">ALOHA</div>
</div>
```

It will fix the parent.